# How can I monitor a ASP.Net Core app with dockerized Prometheus (and Grafana)?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus, docker-for-windows

I would like to have Prometheus and Grafana running on my developer machine using docker-images / docker-for-windows.

I have system-under-development, ASP.Net core, running on localhost:5001 and metrics are showing just fine on https://localhost:5001/metrics.

Docker-compose.yml and prometheus.yml listed below.

- If I include network_mode: host in docker-compose.yml, I can't access
  Prometheus on my physical machine via localhost:9090
- If I exclude
  network_mode and instead use ports: , I can access Prometheus on my
  physical machine via localhost:9090, but checking
  http://localhost:9090/targets, it shows
  https://localhost:5001/metrics as being down.

What am I doing wrong? Any comments welcome!

### docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    container_name: gradle_docker-prometheus
    #network_mode: host
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    volumes:
      - prometheus-storage:/var/lib/prometheus
      - /c/Data/prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    container_name: gradle_docker-grafana
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - grafana-storage:/opt/grafana/data
    depends_on:
      - prometheus

volumes:
  prometheus-storage: {}
  grafana-storage: {}
```

### prometheus.yml:

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s

  external_labels:
      monitor: 'my-project'

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 10s
    scheme: http
    static_configs:
         - targets: ['localhost:9090','cadvisor:8080','node-exporter:9100', 'nginx-exporter:9113']
  - job_name: '.Net'
    scrape_interval: 10s
    scheme: https
    static_configs:
         - targets: ['localhost:5001']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not use host network mode on Windows, it is only supported on Linux. What you need is to change the target address:

```yaml
  - job_name: '.Net'
    scrape_interval: 10s
    scheme: https # You may have to change this to 'http'
                  # or you'd have to create a certificate 
                  # with `host.docker.internal`
    static_configs:
         - targets: ['host.docker.internal:5001']
```

`host.docker.internal` is a special address to connect to the Docker Host, since `localhost` inside a container is just the container itself.

To summarize what goes below in comments: after changing the target to `host.docker.internal`, ensure that your application allows to connect with that host. Run

```
curl http://localhost:5001/ -H "Host: host.docker.internal"
```

and check the answer. If you have an error containing something like this:

> The request hostname is invalid.

Then you've got to find out where the host filter is (it is probably an array containing `localhost` in it) and add the new host (`host.docker.internal`) there.

Comment: Thanks, Anemyte, seem to be precisely what I'm looking for. 

I can't get it to work, though -- my target on host still appear to be offline. curl, apk and apt are not installed on docker-image and ping says 'permission denied - are you root?'. Any suggestions?

I have very basic linux knowledge, I can't even check which distribution I'm running :/

Comment: @AndersJuul well, you can add curl there :) . Add another service with `image: debian:buster` then run `docker-compose run <service_name>`. You'll get into console prompt of this new service where you can `apt update && apt install curl`. Let me know what is the error, I suspect it's either bad protocol\certificate (HTTPS instead of HTTP) or firewall.

Comment: root@6ac68dcf7ffb:/# curl host.docker.internal:57902
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>

Comment: root@6ac68dcf7ffb:/# curl host.docker.internal:57902/metrics
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>

Comment: root@6ac68dcf7ffb:/# ping host.docker.internal
PING host.docker.internal (192.168.65.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.65.2 (192.168.65.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=37 time=10.3 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.65.2 (192.168.65.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=37 time=0.628 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.65.2 (192.168.65.2): icmp_seq=3 ttl=37 time=1.64 ms

Comment: @AndersJuul try `curl -H 'Host: localhost' host.docker.internal:57902/metrics` or replace `localhost` with whatever is working for you when you connect from the host.

Comment: Yes, that is returning correctly the response I'm also getting when accessing localhost:57902/metrics from my physical machine! I can see we're getting close!

Comment: @AndersJuul I hope it's clear that `host.docker.internal` solved your connection problem. The reason why you are getting the error without using `-H 'Host: localhost'` is that your web server (the application or whatever else) has a [host header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host) filter. There should be somewhere a list of allowed hosts and you need to add `host.docker.internal` there. Without the code I can't tell much but it's likely that the list contains `localhost` in it.

Comment: Yes -- thank you very much for the answer and all your help. Answer accepted ;)

Comment: Oops and the bounty too -- I though that was awarded automatically when accepting answer...